# Ubuntu 18.04 server - missing installation candidates while installing mysql-server 8

Tags: apt, server, package-management

I just created a brand new VM with Ubuntu server 18.04 and took the same steps I did earlier on another server (also a brand new 18.04 installation), but this time while attempting to install the mysql-server 8.0 it was suddenly failing.

The steps I followed were:

```
wget -c https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb 
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.10-1_all.deb
```

This configured my sources.list to use the 8.0 instead of the 5.x version of mysql.

Executing `apt-get install mysql-server`, I got:

```
mysql-server : Depends: mysql-community-server (= 8.0.12-1ubuntu18.04) but it is not going to be installed
```

Despite having run commands such as `apt-get clean`, `apt-get install -f` and `apt-get update` several times, and `apt-get upgrade` not reporting any held packages, I found this odd. So I tried `apt install mysql-community-server`.

Which resulted in the same error, but with missing depends for `mysql-community-server-core` and `libmecab2`.

When running `apt install libmecab2` it tells me it has no installation candidate, but according to the ubuntu packages website [it definitely exists in the repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libmecab2).

I couldn't see anything out of the ordinary in my `sources.list` either, and `apt-get update` isn't reporting any errors either.

What could be causing this installation to fail? I took the exact same steps on the physical server, and it worked perfectly on that machine.

Comment: Your packages link tells you that `libmecab2` is in 'universe', so do you have 'universe' repository enabled?  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libmecab2)

Comment: That seems to have fixed it, weird that two installations end up with different configurations

Comment: I suspect you enabled universe on one, but thought it was so obvious you didn't push the idea into your long-term-memory so it never occurred to you for the second one...  (pure guess though)

Comment: nope, I literally did it 2 days ago haha, I just installed the OS and googled for how to install the 8.0 version. (even had to google just now how to enable the universe repo)

Comment: if it really worries you, and you used commands to do everything; compare your `history` between the two machines. If it was me; I'd recognize my adding  ' universe' by the command `sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list` (where I'd have to look in file to see what was done), but you might still see how you added it to both, as only Ubuntu-flavors have 'universe' enabled by default.

Comment: @karel I had no idea this was related to the universe repo when I asked the question. If someone has the same or similar issue and would google it, he/she wouldn't ever find that question/answer either as it's not similar at all.

As such, I find it fair to say it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This package(https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libmecab2
) is in universe repository

Add `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe` 
to your sources.list and run `apt update` to resolve it

or type these command in a terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libmecab2
```

Comment: I find it difficult to mark this as the answer, since @guiverc has been the person who answered the question already in the comments.

Comment: @xorinzor Comments section is not the right place to provide actual solutions as comments can get deleted easily for various reasons. Answers should always be posted in the Answers section. So consider ["accepting" it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) to indicate you've found a working solution and also so that others may more easily find it in the future. Given @ guiverc is an experienced user here, I'm pretty sure they won't mind at all :-)

Comment: @pomsky I suppose. It just doesn't feel right ;)